# Create a filter using Gmail API

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

Google released recently a new version of its Gmail API which now makes possible to [create filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters/create).

However the documentation is quite limited and I'm facing issues to get it working. I'm using the latest version of their [PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). Any help would be appreciated to construct the request body.

```
public $gmail;
public function createFilter($userId) {

    try {

        $filter = new Google_Service_Gmail_Resource_UsersSettingsFilters();
        // Here, we should create the request body...
        // https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters#resource
        // $filter->setCriteria() ??

        $this->gmail->users_settings_filters->create($userId, $filter);


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Logging errors...
    }

}
```

**UPDATE** (Working method)

```
public $gmail;
public function createFilter($userId) {

    try {

       $filter = new Google_Service_Gmail_Filter([
            'criteria' => [
                'from' => 'example@gmail.com'
            ],
            'action' => [
                'addLabelIds' => ['STARRED']
            ]
        ]);

        $this->gmail->users_settings_filters->create($userId, $filter);


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Logging errors...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#making-requests for guidance on constructing request objects.  You should be able to populate the filter properties using native PHP arrays or the autogenerated objects.  Example:

```
$filter = new Google_Service_Gmail_Resource_UsersSettingsFilters([
    'criteria' => [
        'from' => 'somebody@example.com'
    ],
    'action' => [
        'addLabelIds' => ['STARRED']
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brandon. I updated my question with a working solution.

Comment: what if i need to specify more than one email ?