# Create a gmail filter with Gmail API nodejs, Error: Filter doesn't have any criteria

Tags: node.js, gmail, gmail-api

Im having trouble creating a filter with Gmail API using node. Auth and scopes are fine; I get err "Filter doesn't have any criteria". Im guessing that im doing something wrong with headers / body / Resource Parameter, but cant work it out.

Heres the function, I've tried a number of variants:

```
function createFilter(auth){
var gmail = google.gmail({version:'v1','auth':auth});
// Create filter rule
var data = {
  resource: {
    criteria: {
      from: "someone@gmail.com"
    },
    action: {
      removeLabelIds: ["INBOX"]
    }
  },
  userId: 'me'
}

// Send rule to Gmail
gmail.users.settings.filters.create(data, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log( err);
  } else {
    console.log( result );
    callback( result );
  }
 });
};
```

docs:

Create Filter https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters/create
Filter Resource https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters#resource
Making Requests
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#making-authenticated-requests

similar working req in php:

[Create a filter using Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961008/create-a-filter-using-gmail-api)

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

```
function createFilter(auth){
  var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  var data = {
    "criteria": {
      "from": "someone@gmail.com",
    },
    "action": {
      "removeLabelIds": [
        "INBOX",
      ],
    },
  };
  gmail.users.settings.filters.create({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    resource: data,
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log( err);
    } else {
      console.log( result );
      callback( result );
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note :

- If the error of `Insufficient Permission` occurs, please add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic` to the scopes. When the scopes is modified, please remove the file including refresh token and then reauthorize it. By this, new scopes are reflected to the refresh token.

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

I confirmed that when I used v27.0.0, v26.0.1 and v25.0.0 for googleapis, the error of `Filter doesn\'t have any criteria'` occurs. So can you downgrade the version to v24.0.0? When I use v24.0.0, it works fine. It is reported that there are some bugs for the recent updated googleapis for node.js. So I'm using v24.0.0.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I still get the same error, { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'invalidArgument',
       message: 'Filter doesn\'t have any criteria'.

Scope and permissions are correct i believe.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Free Boots I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I found the reason of error. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Working! Thanks @Tanaike

Comment: `service.create_user_setting_filter(user.uid, criteria.from='sender@example.com')` in ruby hw do you pass params